# webdav, open just one particular (/webdav/public/) folder to the world

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, webdav

My webdav stuff is on `/var/www/webdav/`, there I have multiple access roles to enable access to users and groups. And I would like to open one particular folder to the world (/webdav/public/). How do I do that?

I tried:

```
Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav
<Location /webdav>
    DAV On
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
    Require valid-user
</Location>

Alias /webdav/public /var/www/webdav/public
<Directory /var/www/webdav/public>
    DAV On
</Directory>
```

But this way, requesting `http://mysite.ddns.net/webdav/public` asks for credentials.

Comment: Could you start reading the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) instead of asking about every detail please? Also, your questions are unrelated to Samba, why do you tag with this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav
<Location /webdav>
    DAV On
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
    Require valid-user
</Location>

Alias /webdav/public /var/www/webdav/public
<Location /webdav/public>
    DAV On
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

Not sure if the best approach!